# Explaining the parameters of the mitzvah of "Be fruitful and Multiply"

Tags: halacha-theory, conversion-to-judaism, pregnancy-birth

While learning מנחת חינוך last week, I discovered a ruling that if a Gentile had children and he converted afterwards and the children also converted, he does not need to have additional children to fulfill the mitzvah of *Be fruitful and Multiply*. (I'll see if I can locate where I saw this, and edit this, later. Offhand, I think he cites this ruling from Talmud Yevamot.)

My question is if this same ruling applies if a Gentile man married a Jewish woman. They had children, and the children are Jewish by the fact that the mother is Jewish. Later, the man converts. Does he have to have more children?

Factors to consider within this question:

- What are the parameters/requirements of fulfilling the *mitzvah*? Is it the performance of conception, itself? While the children were conceived, the man was a Gentile so he had no obligation to this mitzvah. Therefore, he didn't perform any mitzvah at all.
- Is the obligation to have Jewish children, i.e. once they were born, the children are Jewish. Can that act count as fulfillment of a mitzvah retroactively? His children are Jewish, but he had no mitzvah performance or obligation at the time that they were born.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1149/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Yup. **extremely** relevant. I'll see if I can locate the Ramba"m. I think we can logically deduce an answer from there.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem from the Be'er Heitev in Even HoEzer 1:7 -  [סימן א - דיני פריה ורביה, ושלא לעמד בלא אשה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01974_part_1.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2) - brings a dispute if the convert's children need to be Jewish for him to (retroactively) have his kids considered as his own.

He also discusses that non-Jews are included in the Mitzvah of populating the world. However, some say it means that they are merely forbidden to castrate themselves, but don't need to actually have kids.

So it would seem that if his kids are Jewish to start off with, then once he converts he's fulfilled the Mitzva.

You write `While the children were conceived, the man was a Gentile so he had no obligation to this mitzvah. Therefore, he didn't perform any mitzvah at all.`

That's clearly not the case, as you yourself quoted from the Chinuch. Ditto for your opint #2.

> **ז:** הָיוּ לוֹ בָּנִים בִּהְיוֹתוֹ עוֹבֵד כּוֹכָבִים, *(יא)* וְנִתְגַּיֵּר הוּא וְהֵם, הֲרֵי זֶה קִיֵּם מִצְוָה זוֹ. אֲבָל אִם הָיוּ לוֹ בָּנִים כְּשֶׁהוּא עֶבֶד, וְנִשְׁתַּחְרֵר הוּא וְהֵם, לֹא קִיֵּם מִצְוָה זוֹ עַד שֶׁיּוֹלִיד אַחַר שֶׁנִּשְׁתַּחְרֵר:‏
>
> **באר היטב**  *(יא)* **ונתגייר**. בתשובת מהר''י סג''ל סי' רכ''ג פסק **אפילו לא נתגיירו בניו עמו קיים פו''ר**. וכ''מ מתוספת דיבמות דף ס''ב ע''א ד''ה רי''א קיים פו''ר וכו'. וכנה''ג פסק **דבנים גוים אינם עולים לו לקיום פ''ו** ע''ש. ועיין מ''ש הבה''י. ועי' מ''ש התוספת בחגיגה דף ב' ע''ב ד''ה לא תהו בראה וכו' שסיימו שם ועוד **פרו ורבו אכולהו בני נח כתיב אף לכנען** ע''ש. והיא נגד הסוגיא דפרק ד' מיתות דאמרי' **פו''ר לישראל נאמרה ולא לבני נח** ע''ש וכ''כ המרש''א והניח בצ''ע. ובתשובת שבות יעקב ח''ב סימן קל''ד נשאל עליו והשיב דתו' דחגיגה כתבו זה התירץ למ''ד בני נח מצווין אף על הסירוס כדעת ר' חדקא דאמר הכי בפ''ד מיתות. ואל תתמה ע''ז שהרי הסמ''ג פסק ג''כ הכי וכ''כ הת''ה סימן (רנ''ט) [רצ''ט] הובא דבריו בב''י ס''ס (ו') [ה']. וצריכין אנו לומר דאע''ג דפשוט להש''ס לומר דמצות פ''ו לא נאמרה לבני נח היינו **שאינם מצווים בהכרח לקיים המצות דפו''ר אך הרשות בידם שלא לעסוק כלל בפ''ו אבל לסרס עצמו בענין שא''א להם לעסוק בפ''ו זה ודאי באיסורו קיים** לדעת ר' חדקא וא''כ בהאי חצי עבד וחצי בן חורין דהוי כסירוס ממש שאינו יכול לישא שפחה ולא בת חורין שפיר כתבו תוס' דבענין זה אף הבני נח מצווין עכ''ל. ושמעתי לתרץ ע''פ תוס' דיבמות דס''ב ע''א ד''ה בני פ''ו וכו' וא''ת דפרק ד' מיתות משמע דב''נ לא מיפקדי אפו''ר וי''ל דהכא לאו בני חיוב בפו''ר קאמר אלא **שבניהם נקראים על שמם** ע''ש לפ''ז יש לפרש מה שכתב התוס' בחגיגה דפ''ו אכולהו בני נח כתיב דה''ק דבניהם יקראו על שמם ומינה דשייכי בפ''ו אע''ג דלאו בני חיובא נינהו ע''כ שמעתי ולא הבנתי דהתוספ' מסיימו אף לכנען והתם אמרינן דהכל מודים בעבד שאין לו חייס עי' ודו''ק:‏